# Disable the button during the animation in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, animation

I'm trying to create an app that starts animation after a button click and disables the button while the animation is running. I want to be able to use it multiple times by pressing the button, disabling it, running animation, then reenabling it. So far, I have a button that gets disabled when I press it and then after that I run an animation (blue square moves to the right and then back to starting position), or at least that's what I was hoping for. The reality of the situation is that when a button is pressed, it becomes disabled but no animation occurs. Upon further investigation, I found that the problem results from the use of `setState` while the animation is active. For example, if you `setState` while the animation is running, the animation will just stop. However, I don't understand why setting state before animation begins doesn't work either. I'm using `Animated.View` and this is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Animated, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [dis,setDis] = useState(false)
  const animatedMargin = new Animated.Value(0);
  const slideAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedMargin, { //go right
      toValue: 200,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: false 
    }).start()
    setTimeout(() => {
      Animated.timing(animatedMargin, { //return left
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: false 
      }).start()
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => { setDis(false) }, 2000); //enable button
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop:50 }}>
      <Animated.View style={{ left: animatedMargin }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor:'#00f', height:50, width:50 }}/>
      </Animated.View>
        <Button title='go' disabled={dis}
          onPress={()=>{
            setDis(true),
            slideAnimation()
          }}
        ></Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If I don't use parts of code for disabling and enabling buttons, the animation works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that problem is animated value here. Just wrap it by `useRef` like so:

```
const animatedMargin = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

For example, if your animated value changes from 0 to 1 in 500 ms, when you change state (re-render component) a new instance will be created and lose the current progress, that's why you need to wrap it by the `useRef` hook to create an instance only once.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: @RuKu See my edit.